# Lock orientation of a specific screen

Tags: ios, sencha-touch, cordova

I'm currently developping a mobile app with sencha touch and phonegap. I'd like to provide the option to use the app in landscape mode, but a few screens (parameters, mainly), are ugly in landscape mode, and would be too much work to redesign.

Is there any way to prevent a particular screen from rotating ?

Comment: you want one view in landscape mode ?

Comment: Rather, I want some views to remain in portait mode, even when the app is in landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write code then after generating xcode project edit YOURAPP*.plist file to change `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` to `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`(landscape with button on right) or if you are editing using Xcode's visual editor look for `Supported interface orientations` and change it to whichever orientation you want.

Comment: No, I know how to allow the app to use landscape mode. I want to prevent some view from rotating.